# Can't send emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, ce-1.9.1.0

So here's what I've done:
Loads of customizing using /local copies of /core files.
Updated from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1.

Now I can't send email.
And no, I've ruled out the new >= 1.9 email-queue-through-cron-thingy as root to the error.

When sending invoice updates I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addEmailInfo() on a non-object in /xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php on line 885
```

And this is the same for every email I try to send.
New order gives:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addEmailInfo() on a non-object in /xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php on line 1326
```

...and so on.

This error occur both in front- and backend.
So this has to be central.

And no, it's not the addEmailInfo() that's faulty.

```
$mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
```

$mailer returns empty, so I think the key is here.

I reiterate that this bit is unaltered Magento core so no custimizations here.

Any clues to what's wrong?
Or at least how do I trace this error to it's origin?
Or maybe tips where to start looking.

Comment: What happens if you call `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1)` ? Do you get the same "call to a member function XXXX() on a non-object"?

Comment: If `$mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');` is returning blank / null then this is the issue.  I'm *guessing* you've over-ridden a core file (in local pool) that has since been altered by 1.9.1?  Could you list the items you're overriding?

Comment: @Julien Lachal: I get what can be expected. Or at least not bool(false). It returns a healthy object.
At Douglas Radburn: Well, I meant "bool(false)" rather than just empty. Yes, that's what I thought too and therefore deleted/renamed both /core and /local directories. Then copied /core back from fresh Magento install .zip-file.
I do however suspect residues from uninstalled extensions, but I never did install any extensions that would tamper with the mailing functions. I think. Thanks for swift answers to you both. Most appreciated! =D

Comment: I would suggest removing as many XML files from etc/modules as you can, testing, and putting them back one by one to see if one is causing the issue then :)

Comment: @DouglasRadburn: Thanks! I think I've found clues to a possible culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

An extension, EA Design PDF Invoice PDF Generator (v1.0.18 - v1.0.20), screwed things up.
Connect Manager showed **three** updates for the extension (within five days). The extension coder probably struggled with Magento 1.9 compatibility ;)

Well thanks Julien Lachal and Douglas Radburn for getting me to think in other directions and thus helping me solve this!